# Linebreak problems with PHP's mail and Postfix

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta, line-endings, email-headers

We have some PHP scripts running which send mails using PHP's [mail(](http://www.php.net/mail)) function.

```
$message = "Some lengthy text";

$header = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1; format=flowed\r\n";
$header .= "From: Name <name@example.com>\r\n";
$header .= "Return-Path: <name@example.com>\r\n";

mail('me@example.com', 'Subject', wordwrap($message, 70), $header);
```

In the PHP manual it is mentioned that some UNIX-MTAs don't follow [RFC 2822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2822) and replace LF with LFCR. It looks like that is what is happening to us since *some* of the mails sent have extra line breaks in their *header* part. This screws up the mails since then headers are treated as message body.

```
MIME-Version: 1.0

From: Name <name@example.com>

Message-Id: <20141014171959.B161712E097@mail.mydomain.com>
Date: Tue, 14 Oct 2014 19:19:59 +0200 (CEST)

Some lengthy text
```

However, this problem occurs only with some of our scripts, others work as expected. So it looks like that it is unrelated to our MTA. We are using [Postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) on a [Debian](https://www.debian.org/) system. PHP is configured to use `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i` to send mails. This is the Postfix to Sendmail compatibility interface.
I do not yet see any difference with the scripts where mails are sent correctly and the scripts where mail headers get corrupted. Also copying working code to a new file in the same directory leads to corrupted mails being sent, so I don't think that the PHP code is the source of the problem either.
File encoding and line endings of working scripts and broken scripts is identical, too.

Any thoughts on what else might cause such a behavior?

Comment: Can you post the part of the code where you create the mail headers? Also will be good to have example of broken header. I am using mail() PHP function with Postfix creating dynamic headers without issues ...

Comment: @AntoanMilkov thx for your comment. I added the code and resulting mail headers. That line endings get screwed up seems to be a common problem (even the PHP manual mentions it) but I don't understand why it works for some scripts and for others it doesn't.